# How to add a Keyword Filter for a php jquery database insert?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, insert

I want to make a PHP database insert with jQuery. 
How do I add a Keyword Filter in the code? If I write all the forbidden words in a xml out file `forbidden.xml` Thanks.

insert page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function send(){
    var toUrl = "Data.php";
    var method = 'GET';
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"Data.php",
        data:{
            name:$("#name").val(),
            sex:$("#sex").val()
        },
        beforeSend:function(){
            $("#display").html("Loading...");
        },
        success:function(data){
            $("#display").html(decodeURI(data));
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "insert success";
        },
        error:function(data){
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "insert error";
        }
    });
}
</script>
<form name="input">
    name: <input type="name" name="name" id="name" />
    sex: <input type="sex" name="sex" id="sex" />
    <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="send()" />
</form> 
<div id="display"></div>
```

forbidden.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dictionary language="EN">
    <string>aaa</string>
    <string>bbb</string>
    ...
</dictionary>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your best of doing this server side, whenever your handling validation or sanitation you always handle server side so that it reduces risks.

Firstly you need to understand that your code should be abstract in a way that you do not need to write specific error messages within javascript.

so what you want to do is send all information to the server, get it checked out and return success/error + message from the server like so:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"Data.php",
        data:{
            name:$("#name").val(),
            sex:$("#sex").val()
        },
        beforeSend:function(){
            $("#display").html("Loading...");
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
            if(data.error)
            {
                //Use data.error to alert the user
            }else
            {
                //Use data.message to alert the user
            }
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert("Server Error");
        }
});
```

so your javascript is basically right but your setting static message with javascript, its its not the best idea in the long run.

so with your php, you would validate the data like sio:

```
$name = !empty($_REQUEST['name']) ? $_REQUEST['name'] : false;
$sex = !empty($_REQUEST['sex']) ? $_REQUEST['sex'] : false;
$response = array();
if($name && $sex)
{
    //Load your xml into an array
    foreach($badword as $word)
    {
        if(strstr($name,$word))
        {
            $response["error"] = "Name contains a restricted word (" . $word . ")";
            break 2; //Get out the foreach
        }
    }

    //Validate other items
}

if(!isset($responce["error"]))
{
    $response["success"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Data has been validated";
}

echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointed, so the best write order is `$.ajax`,`your write php code`,`input button`... emmm,`//Load your xml into an array` where to load my xml file? thanks again.